# Use std::lock to protect return statement?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

As I understood, `std::lock` locks section under its scope. But what if access to variable is performed in `return` statement? Example:

```
// Looks safe...
bool foo
{
    std::lock_guard<decltype(myMutex)> tLock(myMutex);
    if (bar == 123)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// Is it safe?
bool foo
{
    std::lock_guard<decltype(myMutex)> tLock(myMutex);
    return bar == 123;
}
```

Comment: Destructor is called after the return, so you are fine in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructor is called after the `return`,

so you are fine in both cases.